# Mac OS X 10.6: run particular command line at terminal start up

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, export, mercurial

I use mercurial and I need to run the command line below each time I open Terminal.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Is there any way to add this command line to Terminal start-up? So I don't have to run this command each time manually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a command can be added to your `.profile` (a text file) in your home folder. The `.profile` (and `.bash_profile` if you use bash) file is run every time you start a new session in Terminal.

Just copy and paste that line into your favourite plain text editor (eg. TextMate, BBEdit, etc.) and save it as `.profile` (NO .txt EXTENSION) in your home folder. Alternatively you can use the command line integration eg. `mate ~/.profile` to make it easier to save.